# SQL how does OR clause work in a JOIN ON query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How does `OR` work in a `JOIN ON` clause? I have a table `games` containing `winner_id` and `opponent_id` and a `teams` table with `team_id` and name columns. Both `opponent_id` and `winner_id` refer to a team in `team_id` and I need it to get the `name` of the teams.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM teams 
LEFT JOIN games ON teams.team_id = games.winner_id 
                OR teams.team_id = games.opponent_id
```

I thought `OR` means insert data if either left or right expression of the operand evaluates to true. But what this does is it creates separate row for `winner_id` and a `opponent_id` instead of all on one row?

My expected result would be that it would join on winner_id as it is the first expression and only get the name for the winner and ignore opponent_id since the first expression was true?

This is the result I am getting:

| team_id | name | game_id | year | round | winner_id | opponent_id | winner_goals | opponent_goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 393 | France | 97 | 2018 | Final | 393 | 394 | 4 | 2 |
| 393 | France | 100 | 2018 | Semi-Final | 393 | 395 | 1 | 0 |
| 393 | France | 104 | 2018 | Quarter-Final | 393 | 400 | 2 | 0 |
| 393 | France | 112 | 2018 | Eighth-Final | 393 | 408 | 4 | 3 |
| 393 | France | 120 | 2014 | Quarter-Final | 409 | 393 | 1 | 0 |
| 393 | France | 123 | 2014 | Eighth-Final | 393 | 413 | 2 | 0 |
| 394 | Croatia | 97 | 2018 | Final | 393 | 394 | 4 | 2 |
| 394 | Croatia | 99 | 2018 | Semi-Final | 394 | 396 | 2 | 1 |
| 394 | Croatia | 101 | 2018 | Quarter-Final | 394 | 397 | 3 | 2 |
| 394 | Croatia | 109 | 2018 | Eighth-Final | 394 | 405 | 2 | 1 |
| 395 | Belgium | 98 | 2018 | Third Place | 395 | 396 | 2 | 0 |
| 395 | Belgium | 100 | 2018 | Semi-Final | 393 | 395 | 1 | 0 |

and my teams table

```
                              Table "public.teams"
 Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 team_id | integer |           | not null | nextval('teams_team_id_seq'::regclass)
 name    | text    |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "teams_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team_id)
    "teams_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "games" CONSTRAINT "games_opponent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (opponent_id) REFERENCES teams(team_id)
    TABLE "games" CONSTRAINT "games_winner_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (winner_id) REFERENCES teams(team_id)
```

and my games table

```
                                          Table "public.games"
     Column     |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
----------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 game_id        | integer               |           | not null | nextval('games_game_id_seq'::regclass)
 year           | integer               |           | not null | 
 round          | character varying(20) |           | not null | 
 winner_id      | integer               |           | not null | 
 opponent_id    | integer               |           | not null | 
 winner_goals   | integer               |           | not null | 
 opponent_goals | integer               |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "games_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (game_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "games_opponent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (opponent_id) REFERENCES teams(team_id)
    "games_winner_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (winner_id) REFERENCES teams(team_id)
```

Comment: I think it is because you do not specify the columns in your select. "*" should select all columns from both tables.

Comment: You select all teams and join all their games no matter whether they won or lost. You outer join the games, which also gives you teams that have not won or lost any game. You can do this, but this is a completely different task from the one you want to solve.

Comment: "My expected result would be that it would join on winner_id as it is the first expression and only get the name for the winner and ignore opponent_id since the first expression was true" - No, `OR` considers the whole expression. There is no first or last; the DBMS can evaluate the conditions in any order it wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, when you use the OR operator in a JOIN ON clause as you've described, it will create separate rows for each matching condition. This behavior is entirely expected. Each row from the teams table will be joined with rows from the games table where either teams.team_id = games.winner_id or teams.team_id = games.opponent_id evaluates to true. This means you'll get multiple rows for each team if they are either the winner or the opponent in multiple games.

If you want to get the names of both the winning team and the opponent team on a single row, you'll need to perform two separate joins, one for each condition:

```
SELECT 
    games.game_id,
    teams_winning.name AS winning_team,
    teams_opponent.name AS opponent_team
FROM games
LEFT JOIN teams AS teams_winning ON games.winner_id = teams_winning.team_id
LEFT JOIN teams AS teams_opponent ON games.opponent_id = teams_opponent.team_id;
```

Comment: It is probably not necessary to outer join the teams. This would only be needed in case there can be games without a winner or loser.